# Regular expression for a table with class name tn_result

Tags: asp.net, regex

what will be the regular expression for a table with class name `tn_result`?

I have tried two expressions given below but neither is working. What is wrong with them? How can I make this work?

```
 string TableExpression = "<TTable class=\"tn_results\">(.*?)</table>";
```

Comment: One happy day, no-one will ask any more questions about how to parse HTML with regular expressions...

Comment: Stackoverflow should really redirect users asking questions containing "regular expression", "html", "table", "class"... directly to http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on why this is a bad idea.

The answer depends on whether you need to get this table server-side or client-side.

On the client, use jQuery:

```
var table = $('table.tn_result');
```

On the client, if you're using ASP.Net WebForms, it will probably be easiest to add `runat="server"` and `id` attributes on the table(s) you want to get. Then you can just get them in the code-behind like any other control:

```
var table = this.TableId; //not really required, but hopefully makes things clear
if(table.Attributes["class"].Contains("tn_result"))
{
    // do something with the table
}
```

Comment: this is not what i am looking for. I need regexpression because i am writting some application for data scrapping.

Comment: Regular Expressions will not work with HTML. You do not actually need a regular expression, you need an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

For scraping HTML use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). It's very flexible and lets you manipulate poorly formed HTML as if it were well-formed XML, so you can use XPATH or just iterate over nodes.